# Audio jack adaptor

Tags: audio, circuit-design, circuit-theory

Can I connect two headphone to each other using a female to female connector and setup communication between the headphones?

Comment: No, it's more complicated than that and too broad and nonspecific for the mission of this site.  Look up "field telephone" circuits to start learning about the subject.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Stratton

Comment: @sribasu: OP probably means 'headset' rather than headphones and is hoping that the microphone of one will drive the speakers of the other without power amplification.

Comment: I understand, but speaker to speaker without amplifier worked for me. Why not he gives a try. It's clear from his question that he is a hobbyist/amateur. Is it worth asking him to read an apparently tough topic before giving it a try. For sure none of the 2 components will get damaged with an amateur try :)

Comment: I had a major typo in my last comment, sorry. In simple words, Headphones can't be used as a microphone because the generated current representing the audio signal will be too low to to generate sound on the other (output) headphone. Instead you can connect a large speaker as microphone and a headphone with low impedence as output to hear it. You can atleast try before learning a book and spending couple of months to understand the topic upside down.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. connecting two loucspeakers in series forms a crude type of telephone.

Speaking loudly into the earpiece of one set of headphones will cause faint sounds in the other set.